# Oracle Apex performance issue due to session state values

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a long-running page in Oracle Apex, this is an interactive report page, which fetches the report based on the Username, From_Date and To_Date parameters users provide.

The query used for this report page is executing without any issues(0.07 Sec) in SQL developer. When I checked the Debug log to debug the long run, I found the statement `"... do not save: same value / password / no session"` in the log which is the reason for the long run. The page never loads and end up in a gateway time out. The expected number of rows for the given parameters in mere 161 rows. Please find the screenshot of the debug log below. Please help me with this.

[image]

At the beginning I found a different issue in the Debug Log, which was due to `'IR binding: "APXWS_MAX_ROW_CNT" value="1000000"'`. Later I removed the Maxrowcount value and made it null. So this was taken care.

Comment: I was able to rectify the issue. The issue was never related to Session state. When I drilled deep down, I was able to find the issue was due to the QUERY. That too the query is having some issue only when it is rendered in Oracle Apex. 

There was a column comparison in where clause with to_char function. I removed this TO_CHAR function and the problem was resolved all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas; see whether any of those helps.

- How do you run the report? Did you set "Page action on selection" for those parameters  to "Submit"?
- If not, how about creating a `SUBMIT` button which would *submit* the page (and, thus, put items' values into session state)?
- If you use a *source* for those items, try to set them to be used "always, replacing any existing value in session state".

Comment: Hi Littlefoot,

Thanks for the help, I was able to rectify the issue. The issue was never related to Session state. When I drilled deep down, I was able to find the issue was due to the QUERY. That too the query is having some issue only when it is rendered in Oracle Apex. There was a column comparison in where clause with to_char function. I removed this TO_CHAR function and the problem was resolved all of a sudden.

Comment: Fine; I'm glad you fixed it.